# Como configuro crontab para rodar URL, comando Linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, cron

Eu criei 4 métodos e quero executá-los acessando o link. Eu já testei os métodos e todos estão funcionando normalmente, mas já tentei diversas configurações pelo `crontab -e`.

Já tentei:

```
0 * * * * wget http://meusite/rota

0 * * * * curl http://meusite/rota
```

Já usei tbm -o minusculo e maiúsculo, e já tentei também usando o caminho do meu projeto, exemplo:

```
0 * * * * curl /var/www/projeto/rota

0 * * * * wget /var/www/projeto/rota
```

Obs: Estou fazendo a configuração pelo root.
Outra coisa, existe um comando para verificar se está funcionando, e como configuro para receber um email cada vez que rodar.

> Meu comando executa um método onde carrega os dados do usuário, nesse
>   método não passo parâmetro algum, pois ele busca todos os usuários

Usei o comando debug para ver o que está acontecendo:

```
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.12 on linux-gnu.


--2016-02-11 16:40:01--  http://caminho/cron
Connecting to 162.243.102.127:80... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000000000b80c90 (new refcount 0).
Deleting unused 0x0000000000b80c90.

---request begin---
GET /blksocial/cron/follow HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: 162.243.102.127
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Thu, 11 Feb 2016 18:40:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

---response end---
500 Internal Server Error
Closed fd 3
2016-02-11 16:40:01 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Antes de qualquer coisa você precisa verificar esse erro 500 retornado pelo servidor.

Comment: Se a resposta abaixo lhe ajudou, por favor clique na marca de verificação ao lado da resposta para marca-la como aceita.

Comment: O erro apresentado é erro 500? Erro 500 é do lado do servidor, não do cliente. Mesmo colocando no cron o caminho do executável (que é recomendado), isso não alteraria o erro

Answer (score 1):

Apenas uma nota, vc deve executar o curl sem saída ou progresso, canalizando para / dev / null assim:
Exemplo rodando de 5 em 5 minutos.

```
 */5 * * * * curl -s http://meusite/rota > /dev/null

 */5 * * * * wget http://meusite/rota
```

Obs: O alias tem que existir pra executar o comando sem o path completo.
Ex: /usr/bin/curl

Esse site pode te ajudar também na questão de tempo:
https://crontab.guru/

:)

Answer (score 0):

Vitor, faça com o seguinte comando:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://meusite/rota
```

Você disse em sua pergunta que utilizou o Curl, mas vi que colocou apenas o comando, então acho que seria o caso de incluir o Path do Curl.

Comment: Seria interessante você explicar brevemente o que o comando faz, assim, sua resposta fica mais completa.

Comment: Meu comando executa um método onde carrega os dados do usuário, nesse método não passo parâmetro algum, pois ele busca todos os usuários.

Comment: @VictorRajesh não entendi seu comentário sobre passar parâmetros ou não, apenas coloquei em minha resposta o comando com o Path do Curl que vc disse ter usado porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Eu quis explicar que que é somente um método simples, que se chamado pela URL funciona como quero. Teria que liberar alguma permissão antes de executar o crontab?