# Executar uma URL cron Cpanel

Tags: libcurl, cron, cpanel

Preciso executar uma URL as 19:00h, todos os dias.
Tentei fazer pelo cron job do cpanel, mas a url não é executada.

```
curl -s -o /dev/null http://minhaurl.com.br/index.php/sms/enviodiario
```

O que estaria de errado?

Comment: Testou sem o cron, diretamente pelo console? Outro ponto, é, se o site estiver dentro do próprio servidor, poderia executar diretamente o php, sem precisar da url ou uso de webserver (apache, etc)

Comment: Então, não sei como funciona sem o cron, e está dentro do servidor sim, porém, como é models, e controllers, não sei como eu poderia executar este arquivo, não quero fazer um arquivo separado pra conexão, queria executar a url em si, que chama os métodos certinho

Comment: o fato de ter "models" e "controls" não afeta em nada.. rsrs.. aí que está a importância de um sistema versátil. Poder fazer a requisição também via CLI (command line interface).. mas se o sitema não está preparado para o modo CLI, não tem jeito.. ou implementa ou faz assim mesmo. Isso é um outro assunto, mas achei interessante comentar

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo de como usar o cron chamando um PHP, caso seja no mesmo servidor. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124519/ - basta trocar o caminho do artisan pelo do seu PHP. Se for na mesma máquina, não faz o mínimo sentido uma requisição HTTP (aliás, geralmente acaba sendo gambiarra, se não tivar nada que requisite um método HTTP específico, o que seu caminho na pergunta indica). Inclusive, chamando o PHP diretamente, você pode executar tarefas mais longas sem problema de timeout nem de concorrência com o servidor web.

Comment: sobre o curl, tem que certificar-se de que o curl está disponível no seu bash. Pode tentar outra ferramenta como o wget, por exemplo.

Comment: Outras postagens sobre o mesmo assunto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112587/70 - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38725/70

Comment: @Bacco Ok, mas não consegui adaptar isto a minha realidade... ele executou conforme a resposta do nosso amigo, porém, não deu nenhum resultado...

Comment: Não tem muito o que adaptar, é só copiar literalmente e por o caminho. Se não funcionar é problema no código, e aparece no log de erro.

Comment: Sim, compreendi perfeitamente, porém, como o sistema é MVC, como eu conseguiria executar o model?

Comment: Uma tarefa dessas não deveria ser escrita como parte do MVC, afinal é uma rotina de manutenção, sequer precisa de interação normal com usuário. Independente disso, o modelo em si não deve afetar em nada, pois o PHP chamado pela linha de comando é o mesmo que o servidor de páginas chama. Agora, se você está dependendo de rotas ou coisa do tipo, sinal que é hora de simplificar a arquitetura.

Comment: Ele executa normalmente, porém, não faz o que estava esperando... chega o retorno normal no email.

Comment: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   300  100   300    0     0  19565      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  292k

Comment: Especificidades da aplicação já fica mais dificil de palpitar sem saber seu código. Provavelmente falta algum detalhe bobo só, lembre de dar uma olhada no seu log de erros pra ver se está tudo em ordem.

Comment: Então @Bacco, se eu executar esta URL, normal, no navegador, a função é chamada normalmente e me traz o resultado esperado. Preciso executar esta função todos os dias as 08 da manhã

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenta isto aqui

```
wget -O /dev/null http://minhaurl.com.br/index.php/sms/enviodiario
```

quando preciso utilizar faço desta forma, veja e o curl esta habilitado no seu servidor e se caso vc queira usar com curl vc faz nesta ordem

```
curl http://minhaurl.com.br/index.php/sms/enviodiario -o /dev/null
```

não sei se influencia mas é assim que tenho usado no meu servidor com cpanel

Comment: Como eu sei que o comando foi executado? há algum retorno no cpanel?

Comment: Ele executou normal, mas não deu muito certo... :/

Comment: basta você tirar o /dev/null e configura o e-mail de retorno para o seu e-mail, e na sua url basta vc dar um print na resposta ou relatorio que tudo q for exibido na tela vai para o seu email

Comment: Estou tentando, mas não deu certo mesmo... não vem o retorno, e não executa a função que eu preciso, mas se eu acesso via url normal, funciona

Comment: Dentro do seu código php use a função para envio de email, assim você receberá um email toda vez que for executado.